# What indexes do I need to define for my bridging tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design, index

I have three tables in my database:

**users:**

- user_id (PK)

**roles:**

- role_id (PK)

**users_roles:**

- user_id (PK, FK)
- role_id (PK, FK)

I've done plenty of research surrounding indexing columns but I can't find a definitive answer to my question which is what columns should be indexed in this bridging scenario when I have a compound primary key. I need to be able to conduct WHERE queries using both user_id and role_id in the bridging table. I've read mixed answers and don't understand how many indexes need to be defined.

My current indexes for this bridging table include:

- PRIMARY (user_id, role_id)
- INDEX (user_id)
- INDEX (role_id)

I assume ^ is incorrect.

Comment: Here is a discussion of such:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `PRIMARY KEY` is already a clustered indexed. It will also speed up queries executed against first column in an index, but not the other.

So if you index is defined on `user_id`, `role_id` (in that order), index will work also for `user_id`.

In your situation I'd go with default index of compound key, then, if needed, take a closer look at long running queries and benchmark if separate index on `role_id` is necessary.

Comment: Ok, so in my case the INDEX user_id should be removed because the PRIMARY cluster covers it?

Comment: @Owen No, it won't be removed, but it's unnecessary. But you must keep in mind that every index requires some additional processing when inserting or deleteing records, so you don't want to have many indexes, which are not necessary. And, as I said, everything depends. If you encounter some long running queries, you might benchmark if additional indexes help, but for start, you need only additional index on `role_id`, but only if you have queries that may benefit from that index, don't create unnecessary indexes.

Comment: @Michal, I think he is asking whether he should remove the index. The answer is yes which I beleive we both agree on